# Number of zeros in decimal expansion

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the number of zeros in the decimal expansion of $11^{100}-1$?

Comment: According to python 12. Your number is 137806123398222701841183371720896367762643312000384664331464775521549852095523076769401159497458526446000.

Comment: how can it be solved using some theorems?

Comment: Or if that's binary, you have 3^4 - 1 = 80, so the answer is 1 zero in the decimal expansion.

Comment: You can easily show that $11^{100} - 1$ has exactly $3$ trailing $0$'s.  However, the $0$'s in the middle of the number are not really very amenable to analysis.

Answer (score 2):

11^100 - 1 = 137806123398222701841183371720896367762643312000384664331464775521549852095523076769401159497458526446000 which has 12 zeros.

Answer (score 2):

We ca see that,

$$11^{100}-1=(10+1)^{100}-1=(10^{100}+100\cdot10^{99}+99\cdot50\cdot 10^{98}+...+1)-1$$

Now, try to investigate the above.